# Column value to be displayed on the header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am doing a report using SSRS-2008R2.I have done all the work and table.I have column("Dept").It is done group by and so that the output has each Dept values in a separate page.I also need to keep the Dept value in the header.How to keep it to the header??.When I tried to directly drag the column from dataset to the header it shows the first value of Dept to all the pages.help me with that

Ex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSh9O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw7FF.png)

So, in the second image the header should have the Dept value of A0110 but it is showing the same value of 1st one's(A0100)

Comment: Did you add a parent group for Dept? If so, then you should have added the Header row for that.

Comment: It seems you need to create a [column group](http://www.tutorialgateway.org/grouping-in-ssrs-matrix-reports)

Comment: Updated the question with image.please check that and give solution

Comment: What is the expression of that textbox? Specify the Group in the scope